# NodeJs List filenames inside a file with absolute path

Tags: node.js

I am using windows and have this folder:

```
c:\myfiles
```

Inside that directory I have some files.

So:

```
getfilesList() {
    mypath: 'c:\myfiles'
    // code to get file list here
}
```

How can I do this?

ps: I found quite a few examples but none worked for me for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a local tool and need not asynchronous methods, you can just use [`fs.readdirSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options). Do not forget to escape Windows delimiters in your path:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const filenamesArray = fs.readdirSync('C:\\Program Files\\nodejs');
console.log(filenamesArray);
```

Output:

```
[ 'install_tools.bat',
  'node.exe',
  'nodevars.bat',
  'node_etw_provider.man',
  'node_modules',
  'npm',
  'npm.cmd',
  'npx',
  'npx.cmd' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation of `fs` (FileSystem) in the [Node website](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)
The function you search is `fs.readdir(yourPath)`
Hope this help!